# Angular NX/Jest testing of a directive and passing different test Users

Tags: angular, jestjs

I'm using Nx with Angular and Jest (with MockUtils library). I've got a test file of a structural directive and I want different tests for different Users (who have different levels of authorization). If a user is an admin they see 4 apps and if they're not, they see 2. I'll try and just add the relevant example code:

```
const testUser1 = {
    "role": "admin"
}
const testUser2 = {
    "role": "regularJoe"
}

describe('MyStructuralDirective', () => {
    let fixture: Component<TestHostComponent>;
    let component: TestHostComponent
    let authService: AuthService;

    beforeEach(() => {
         TestBed.configureTestingModule({
             imports: [],
             declarations: [
                 MyStructuralDirective,
                 TestHostComponent
             ],
             providers: [
                 MockUtils.mockProvider( AuthService, {
                     user$: new BehaviorSubject<any | null>(null),
                     isAuthorized: jest.fn((someFlag: string) => {
                         const user = authService.user$.value as any;
                         console.log(`USER: ${user.role}`);
                         return user.role === 'admin';
                     })
                 });
             ],
             schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
         }).compileComponents();
         fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
         authService = TestBed.inject(AuthService);
         component = fixture.componentInstance;
     });

     afterEach(() => jest.clearAllMocks());
     
     test('should display two apps for user 1', () => {
         authService.user$.next(testUser1 as any);
         fixture.detectChanges();
         expect(component.numApps).toBe(2);
     });

     test('should display four apps for user 2', () => {
         authService.user$.next(testUser2 as any);
         fixture.detectChanges();
         expect(component.numApps).toBe(4);
     });
    
});
```

Here's a snippet of the Directive under test:

```
ngOnInit(): void{
    this.authService.user$.subscribe({
        next: user => {
            if(user) this.authService.isAuthorized(someFlag) ? this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef) : null;
        }
    });
}
```

When I run the tests, no apps are coming thru. It's always the same:

```
 Expected: 2 (or whatever number i have in the assertion)
 Received: 0
```

Clearly, it's got to be something that I'm not understanding about the Angular Change Detection process. But the console statement in the *isAuthorized()* method is outputting the correct role, i.e. *Admin* and then *RegularJoe*. So, the user is getting updated and the ngOnInit() is being run.

I guess that I'm putting my assertions in the wrong place??? Can anyone shed any light, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have asynchronous code here, and should check it with same test pattern. For example you can use `fakeAsync` wrapper for your tests:

```
test('should display two apps for user 1', fakeAsync(() => {
   authService.user$.next(testUser1 as any);
   fixture.detectChanges();

   tick();

   expect(component.numApps).toBe(2);
}));
```